# response time childElementCount delayed

Tags: javascript, html

basically i need to get in real time the quantity of numbers added, depending on whether I add or remove these numbers, but the way i did it has a very annoying delay, assigns the function to the add button and it only updates when it is pressed, so if i add a number by pressing it, it does not update until i add another one and if i remove a number by pressing x nothing happens

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

```js
// add dozens
var form = document.getElementById('addForm');
var itemList = document.getElementById('items');

function childCount() {
  var x = document.getElementById("items").childElementCount;
  var x = eval(x);

  document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = " " + x + " selected";
}

// Form submit event
form.addEventListener('submit', addItem);
// Delete event
itemList.addEventListener('click', removeItem);



// Add item
function addItem(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get input value
  var newItem = document.getElementById('item').value;

  // Create new li element
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  // Add class
  li.className = 'list-group-item';

  // Add text node with input value
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItem));



  // Create del button element
  var deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');

  // Add classes to del button
  deleteBtn.className = 'btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete';

  // Append text node
  deleteBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('X'));

  // Append button to li
  li.appendChild(deleteBtn);

  // Append li to list
  itemList.appendChild(li);

}

// Remove item
function removeItem(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
    if (confirm('confirme para remover a aposta')) {
      var li = e.target.parentElement;
      itemList.removeChild(li);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <form id="addForm">
    <div class="sel">select
      <input type="number" class="adds" id="item" min="0" max="99" value="0"> </input>
      <button onclick="childCount()">add</button>
    </div>
  </form>


  <ul id="items"> </ul>
  <div id="Result" value="0">selected</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i make some changes in your code and now its working like you want :

```js
// add dozens
var itemList = document.getElementById('items');
var result = document.getElementById('Result');
var input = document.getElementById('item');

function childCount() {
    result.innerHTML = itemList.childElementCount + " selected"
}


// Add item
function addItem(e) {

  // Get input value
  var newItem = input.value;

  // Create new li element
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  // Add class
  li.className = 'list-group-item';

  // Add text node with input value
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItem));



  // Create del button element
  var deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');

  // Add classes to del button
  deleteBtn.className = 'btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete';

  deleteBtn.onclick = (e)=>{
    removeItem(e);
  }

  // Append text node
  deleteBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('X'));

  // Append button to li
  li.appendChild(deleteBtn);

  // Append li to list
  itemList.appendChild(li);

  childCount();
}

// Remove item
function removeItem(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
    if (confirm('confirme para remover a aposta')) {
      var li = e.target.parentElement;
      itemList.removeChild(li);
      childCount();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="childCount()">
    <div id="main">
          <div class="sel">select
            <input type="number" class="adds" id="item" min="0" max="99" value="0"> </input>
            <button onclick="addItem()">add</button>
          </div>
      
      
        <ul id="items"> </ul>
        <div id="Result" value="0"></div>
      </div>
      <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```